# Kafka Broker State using client

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

Any way to get Kafka Broker State other than JVM metrics(e.g. Kafka AdminClient).

https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

Answer (score 1):

AdminClient-equivalent functions exist in many other languages.

Or you can deploy services like Confluent REST Proxy to get cluster information over HTTP

If you want to monitor the cluster, then you're stuck with JMX, but can change that to HTTP using Prometheus JMX Exporter, Jolokia, etc

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer. Any specific way using AdminClient API's.
Also if we consider it doing remotely.

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for exactly. The JavaDoc for the AdminClient class shows you all the methods you need to get Cluster/Topic state. It **does not** get metrics. For this, you need to use other tools that I mentioned. which have nothing to do with Kafka, and are used for any JVM application

Comment: True, but the API doesn't get the status of the Broker or say the Cluster doesn't have any stats that can help to determine whether the number of brokers is the same as configured. Also, the API doesn't help get Kafka disk usage.

Comment: As mentioned, most of that would be only from JMX, which is not specific to Kafka. To get number of brokers, yes, you would use `AdminClient.describeCluster()`. Or you can count the number of JMX exporters reporting data. For disk usage, I think Prometheus node_exporter can help with that.